# Hirsch, Smale, and Devaney's "Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and an Introduction to Chaos" - polar coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, polar-coordinates, stability-in-odes

To study the system
$$x' = −y +\epsilon x(x^2 + y^2)\\
y' = x +\epsilon y(x^2 + y^2),$$

the authors perform a change of coordinates, getting
$$r'=\epsilon r^3\\
\theta'=-1.$$

So, they state that

> Thus when $\epsilon>0$, all solutions spiral away from the origin, whereas when
> $\epsilon<0$, all solutions spiral toward the origin.

I cannot see this because, trying to solve the firt ODE, I found
$$r^2(t) = \dfrac{1}{2(c-\epsilon t)}.$$

If $\epsilon>0$, the $r$ is not real for $t$ large.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution is correct,

$$r(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{r(0)^{-2} - 2\,\epsilon\,t}},$$

but the solution does grow unbounded when $\epsilon > 0.$ In this DE, your constant $c$ is necessarily positive as it is effectively a multiple of the initial distance from the origin. In fact, this DE has finite escape time for $\epsilon > 0$: the solution $r(t) \to \infty$ as $t\to \frac{1}{2\,\epsilon}\,r(0)^{-2}.$ When $\epsilon < 0,$ the solution $r(t) \to 0$ as $t\to\infty.$

Comment: Oh, thank you. I had never heard about 'finite escape time' before!